# Is the arbitrary union of consecutively non-disjoint path-connected sets path-connected?

Tags: real-analysis

We have proven this statement for finite unions but does it also hold true for arbitrary (e.g. infinite) unions? The sequence of sets has the property that the intersection of two subsequent sets is non-empty.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: What kind of ordered set is the given family of sets indexed by?

Comment: The long line springs to mind; intuitively I would think you can write it as an appropriate union, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @EricStucky after some thinking it seems that the extended long line might not work. The point at infinity isn't connected by a path to anything else.

Comment: @EricStucky the problem is that any point $(\alpha,a)$ has uncountably many copies of $[0,1)$ between it and $\infty$.

Comment: @kahen: Whaaa? Doesn't the long line only use countable ordinals? [Edit: Oh, *extended*. Because the ordinary one is also path-connected. Got it.]

Comment: I should also have asked if the question is about path connectedness or just plain connectedness (i.e., inability to write the set as a disjoint union of two nonempty open sets).

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen The post was initially about plain connectedness but I meant to ask about path-connectedness.